# Javascript - append pieces of text and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to build a webpage that has a "terminal look" where text seems to be being typed.

I'm doing this by loading a .txt file contents into a string var, setting a "speed" (int) which will define how many characters to read at a time, and then calling the write function inside a `setInterval`. On the write function, I select the bit of text to write with `$("#console").append(text.substring(index, (index+speed)));` and then increment with `index += speed`

However, the .txt contents have plain text as well as Html tags ( to format the text ), and when those contents are typed into the brower, the html tags don't appear right. For example a bit of text on my txt that looks like `<span> This is a test </span>` will appear like `> This is a test! </span>` ( Instead of just "This is a test" )

If I used the `.html(str)` and pass the substring as `.substring(0, index)` the contents will be typed correctly, but this doesn't work for me as I would like to load multiple .txt into the same page, and .html() just replaces the whole content.

I know this is a bit confusing, it's also hard to explain so feel free to ask anything you didn't understand.

Comment: can you show some line of this page form where you are getting this text

Comment: I did, the first line.  `<span> This is a test </span>`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [TypedJS](http://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)

It is dependent on [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to decode the HTML string. Try this:

```
var decodedString = $("<div />").html(text.substring(index, (index+speed))).html();
$("#console").append(decodedString);
```

This basically creates a div, parses and creates the html inside that div. Then we get the html from the div and append where we actually want it to be.

**EDIT**:

So your issue is that you are breaking up `<span> This is a test </span>` into smaller chunks. Appending any partial html will never work. jQuery can't properly parse it. `<spa` + `n>stuff` + `</sp` + `an>` can not be individually inserted and expect it to be rendered correctly. Sometimes jQuery will try to fill in missing parts but don't rely on that. Instead break your text up into spans:

```
var decoded1 = $("<div />").html("<span> Thi</span>").html();
var decoded2 = $("<div />").html("<span>s is a tes</span>").html();
var decoded3 = $("<div />").html("<span>t </span>").html();

$("#console").append(decoded1);
$("#console").append(decoded2);
$("#console").append(decoded3);
```

And then of course you will no longer need to decode anything. You can just directly append those pieces and it will work.

```
$("#console").append("<span> Thi</span>");
$("#console").append("<span>s is a tes</span>");
$("#console").append("<span>t </span>");
```

Comment: Can you explain in further detail what this does ? I tried it but it's not working, the outcome is exactly the same. I'm just not sure if I need to adjust it for the html tags i'm using inside the txt

Comment: Well you said that using `.html()` worked. but always replaced everything. So I suggested using `.html()` but with a throw away div and then getting the html from that div and appending it `console`. I am surprised that didn't work.

Comment: See? http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/xtLsyz8h/ Are you sure the values being pulled out are the correct string and not something like `> This is a test </span>`?

Comment: Well in that example you're adding the whole string in just one go. But to get the typer effect, i'm adding the text in little chunks ( like 5 characters at a time, in a 30ms interval ).  So the first chunk is just `<span` and the second will be `> Thi` and so on.. See  http://jsfiddle.net/xtLsyz8h/2/

Comment: Thats exactly your issue then. You have to load full html not partial tags. I would suggest breaking up the string pieces into separate spans for every text chunk.

Comment: I see where you're going but the txts will be rather large and have different html tags, including css class assignments

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately there is no other way to go. You can't insert partially formed HTML into the DOM. It just won't work. Ever. You need to figure out a different way to do it.

Comment: Well thanks for all the help anyway, i really appreciate it.

Right now I'm trying another approach -  to use a function that returns the html content of the div, and then use the .html(currentContent + text.substring(...) );

Comment: Well just to let you know jQuery/browser is going to attempt to fix your messed up html by adding or removing portions. You can never guarantee when passing partially formed HTML to jQuery or the DOM that it will look the same. Therefore whatever you put in your .txt file will not be what you see in the DOM when its all over. Try if you want but again, it will not work. If I pass `<div>` to the browser it will automatically close that div and everything you wanted inside it will be outside it. And If i give `</div>` to the browser it will throw it away because it doesn't find the opening tag.